# Transfer function $G(s)=\frac{1}{(s+7)(s+12)}$ and input $x(t)=(1+1/t)^t$, calculate the limit of the output $y(t)$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: laplace-transform

So I have the following:

$G(s)=\dfrac{1}{(s+7)(s+12)}$, $ȳ(s)=\dfrac{x̄(s)}{(s+7)(s+12)}$

Since $x(t)=(1+1/t)^t$ which is $e$ as t tends towards infinity, can I simply say that $L(x(t))=x̄(s)=e/s$

The question was to calculate the limit of the output $y(t)$ as t tends towards infinity. Using the converging input converging output theorem, I have

$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=x_\infty=e$

$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}y(t)=G(0)x_\infty=e/84$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. On a mathematical side note, it is important for your argument aht $G(s)$ has no singularity for $\mathop{\rm Re}(s)\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the final value theorem which states that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=\lim_{s\rightarrow0} s F(s)
\end{equation}

where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transfort of $f(t)$. So \begin{equation}
\lim_{s\rightarrow0} s \frac{e}{s} \dfrac{1}{(s+7)(s+12)} =\frac{e}{84}
\end{equation}

Comment: Notice that you can only use the final value theorem when the poles of $\text{s}\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right)$ are in the right half-plane (when $\Re\left(\text{s}\right)<0$)